# Getting "Android resource linking failed" even though my code has not changed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-resources

Recently I have been getting this error while running my app:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Ved\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\17b6ef056be36c409382a0a8037faedc\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

And:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Ved\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\17b6ef056be36c409382a0a8037faedc\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

When I click on it, it takes me to values.xml line 150:

```
<declare-styleable name="ColorStateListItem">
        <!-- Base color for this state. -->
        <attr name="android:color"/>
        <!-- Alpha multiplier applied to the base color. -->
        <attr format="float" name="alpha"/>
        <attr name="android:alpha"/>
        <!-- Perceptual luminance applied to the base color. From 0 to 100. -->
        <attr format="float" name="lStar"/>
        <attr name="android:lStar"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

I don't even use this styleable yet the error persists. I have read posts talking about the problem being with my `compileSDK` or with `android-core:core-ktx:+`
However when i change the SDK to 31 and `android-core:core-ktx:1.7.0` it still doesn't work and gives me another error. I have been trying to find the answer but I haven't been able to and hopefully one of you can.
Here are my build gradles:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.suad.venttome"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    //Passcode view
    implementation 'com.hanks:passcodeview:0.1.2'

    //Material.io implementation
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'


    //Android Jetpack Navigation
    def nav_version = "2.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

AND:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.30-M1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If you have a possible solution I would love to her it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

with version `1.7.0` it also does't work for me

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work either. Instead I get this error `Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=15}.
           The dependency contains Java 8 bytecode. Please enable desugaring by adding the following to build.gradle
           android {
               compileOptions {
                   sourceCompatibility 1.8
                   targetCompatibility 1.8
               }
           }`